# How to increase gpu memory for Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, gpu, out-of-memory

I am using NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Super with 24GB gpu memory in total . When I try to train a RES101 model using Pytorch, the cuda memory runs out during training time. I found that only 8GB gpu memory is saved for Pytorch. I wonder if I can increase the gpu memory allocated for it.

Comment: Hi. How exactly did you find that "only 8GB gpu memory is saved for Pytorch" ?

Comment: A single RTX 2070 does not have 24GB GPU memory.  If you have multiple GPUs then try these,
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html